# Updating or saving a form field using cleaned_data in Django not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

It is simple, but I don't know why it is not working! I just want to set my **TOTAL** field from the form with the **PRE-TOTAL** value. It is updating my FORM_DATA (instance using cleaned_data), but not saving! It is still coming with the default value!!!
Would someone tell me why?

Here go the codes:

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class av_pomades(models.Model):
    cod_prod = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    pic = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


pomades_to_chose = (
    ('Suavecito - water based','Suavecito - water based'),
    ('Reuzel Blue - water based','Reuzel Blue - water based'),
    ('Layrite - water based','Layrite - water based'),
    ('Suavecito - oil based','Suavecito - oil based'),
    ('Reuzel Pink - Oil Based','Reuzel Pink - Oil Based'),
    ('Layrite - oil based','Layrite - oil based')
)

class order_form(models.Model):
    pomade = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=pomades_to_chose)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ord_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    total = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pomade
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
from dataclasses import fields
from tabnanny import verbose
from django import forms
from . import models

class order_forms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # model that the fields will come from
        model = models.order_form
        # chosing the fields to be displayed
        fields = ['pomade', 'amount', 'total']
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import av_pomades, order_form
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import forms

@login_required(login_url='accounts:login')
def purchase(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.order_forms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # creating a cleanned data instace
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            ch_pomade = str(form_data['pomade'])

            # retrieving the right price from the selected product 
            pomades_prices = av_pomades.objects.all().values('name','price')        
            for pomades_data in pomades_prices:
                if ch_pomade in pomades_data['name']:
                    ch_pomade_price = pomades_data['price']

            # setting the total price
            famount = int(form_data['amount'])
            pre_total = ch_pomade_price * famount
            
            # updating the price in the for to be recorded in DB
            
            **# HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART I GUESS**
            form_data['total'] = pre_total
            print(form_data)           
            

            form.save()
            return redirect('products:order_success')
    else:
        form = forms.order_forms()
    return render(request,'basquet.html', {'order_form':form})
```

Comment: The problem in your code is with the variable `ch_pomade_price`. You must in principle declare it before assigning a value to it in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the answers in this question [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) to understand the specifics of what you were facing.

In your case, you are not updating the form data but a variable that is an independent copy of the form data

WRONG
`form_data['total'] = pre_total`

CORRECT
`form.cleaned_data['total'] = pre_total`